# Unordered_map : key_hash and key_equal

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I need help to understand this part of code. The code defines two of the template arguments of unordered_map. All I understand uptill now is that you have to define your own hash function for user defined keys. This code is written for a tuple having int,char,char as a key and this tuple is used as a key in unordered_map. Please explain What is happening in 
key_hash and key_equal.

```
struct key_hash : public std::unary_function<key_t, std::size_t>
{
  std::size_t operator()(const key_t& k) const
  {
   return std::get<0>(k) ^ std::get<1>(k) ^ std::get<2>(k);
  }
};

struct key_equal : public std::binary_function<key_t, key_t, bool>
{
  bool operator()(const key_t& v0, const key_t& v1) const
  {
   return (
   std::get<0>(v0) == std::get<0>(v1) &&
     std::get<1>(v0) == std::get<1>(v1) &&
     std::get<2>(v0) == std::get<2>(v1)
  );
  }
```

[Full code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dede823b40af4662)

Comment: The first is providing a simple hash by logically ORing together the three values. The second is comparing the three values to determine equality.